# Application resp. WebApplication Context Spring Rest Service with DataRepositopries deploy on Google App Engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I' ve a Spring Boot Restservice with Spring DataRepositories which I want to deploy on Google App Engine.

As running as a Spring Application I now intialize the Application Context and the  DataRepositories in the *main* Method of the Spring Application and provide static Access from there (..and i dont know if tis is best practise!?).

But when I deploy I to GAE the *main* Method is ommitted, which i understand because it runs in a WebApplication Context.

- i want static applicationwide  access to my DataRepositories.
- i want to dynamically load the reqiured Application resp. WebApplication Context wether the Appp runs as Spring Application or 
  WebApplication on Google App Engine
- i dont want to change code when i switch between GAE Application and Spring Application

any help would be appreciated ... thx

**my main method of the Spring Application gets not processed on GAE:**

```
public class Application {

    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;
    public static TblGpsRepository DataRepository;
    public static TblTracksRepository DataRepositoryTracks;
    public static TblUserRepository DataRepositoryUser;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx= SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);


        DataRepository=ctx.getBean(TblGpsRepository.class);
        DataRepositoryTracks=ctx.getBean(TblTracksRepository.class);
        DataRepositoryUser = ctx.getBean(TblUserRepository.class);


    }
```

**my Controller code where I access the repositoroies:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/TblGps/getList/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody
        List<TblGps> findAll()
        {
            logger.debug("/TblGps/getList");
           return   Application.DataRepository.findAll();
        }
```